# php-mbstring no package available on RHEL6?

Tags: php, redhat

```
[root@ltfs1968 yum.repos.d]# yum install php-mbstring
Loaded plugins: dellsysid, downloadonly, replace, rhnplugin
This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or RHN Satellite.
Setting up Install Process
No package php-mbstring available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Just finished removing the webtatic repository and installed php and mysql.  I need to now install the mbstring package and it returns this.

I've done some searching and it seems RHEL's repo does not have it.  How can I add this without upgrading or downgrading from PHP 5.3.3, and without switching repos permanently or ruining my setup?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's in the "RHEL Server Optional repository".
You need to subscribe your machine to that repository via RHN.

Comment: How can I do this?

Comment: Probably https://access.redhat.com/solutions/70019 but I don't have access to a RedHat subscription anymore to confirm.

Comment: I've removed all extra repos and disabled them, and removed PHP.  How can I get PHP 5.3.* on my system to work with php-mbstring and php-devel?

Comment: Well, you need the Base repo (or whatever it is called in RHEL now) and the one I mentioned. Then just run `yum install php-mbstring php-devel`.

Comment: @NoahMatisoff You need to _add_ the repo, not _remove_ it!